# Multiple textfields in form not working

Tags: forms, api, drupal

I have created a form with multiple textfields. The textfields get default values from the DB. The forms are within a table, but some cells disappear. It is strange because when I change some values in the DB, they may show up. Can anyone help?

```
$matches = competition_entry_load(); 
    $form['namefield'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('check'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => FALSE,
  );

  foreach ($matches as $key=>$entry) {
    $A1 = $entry->A1;   
    $AX = $entry->AX;
    $A2 = $entry->A2;
    $home_team = $entry->home_team;
    $away_team = $entry->away_team;


    $form['namefield'][$A1] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => $A1,
    '#size' => 6,
    '#maxlength' => 6,
    '#prefix' => '<table border=0 cellspacing=30 celladding=30><tr><td><center>',
    '#suffix' => '</center></td>',
  ); 



    $form['namefield'][$AX] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => $AX,
    '#size' => 4,
    '#maxlength' => 4,
    '#prefix' =>'<td><center>',
    '#suffix' => '</center></td>',
  ); 

    $form['namefield'][$A2] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => $A2,
    '#title'=> t($A2),
    '#size' => 4,
    '#maxlength' => 4,
    '#prefix' =>'<td><center>',
    '#suffix' => '</center></td>',
  ); 

    $form['namefield'][$home_team] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => $entry->home_team,
    '#size' => 15,
    '#maxlength' => 15,
    '#prefix' =>'<td><center>',
    '#suffix' => '</center></td>',
  ); 

    $form['namefield'][$away_team] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => $entry->away_team,
    '#size' => 15,
    '#maxlength' => 15, 
    '#prefix' =>'<td><center>',
    '#suffix' => '</center></td>',
  );


    $form['namefield']['skorH_'.$home_team] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#size' => 1,
    '#maxlength' => 1,
    '#prefix' =>'<td><center>',
    '#suffix' => '</center></td>',
  ); 

    $form['namefield']['skorA_'.$home_team] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#size' => 1,
    '#maxlength' => 1,
    '#prefix' =>'<td><center>',
    '#suffix' => '</center></td></tr></table>',
  ); 
}

return $form;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of the HTML output?

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the prefixes and suffixes entirely? The layout won't be what you want, but you'll at least know if the form fields are there, with the right data. If they are, then your problem is 'just' about incorrect HTML, not anything to do with using the Forms API incorrectly.

Comment: The fault is reproduced with or without prefixes and suffixes.

Comment: The same fault is also reproduced with just one field (eg $form['namefield'][$AX] ) whenever there are same values from db.Very strange...

Answer (score 0):

I think the bug is with the variable values you are using as the keys for $form array. If within the loop the value of $A1, $A2, etc repeat at any point, then the values are overridden. See that the values of $A1, $A2, etc are unique.